# if and foreach in a templating engine

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach, template-engine

I'm working on a templating engine (I don't want to use an already existing one) and it works fine. This is the code I have now:

```
class template {

    private $vars = array();
    public $page;

    function __construct() {
    }

    public function render($render = false) {
            $page = $this->page . '.php';
            $content = file_get_contents($page);

            foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value) {
                $tag = '{' . $key . '}';
                $content = str_replace($tag, $value, $content);
            }

            if ($render)
                echo $content;
            else
                return $content;
    }

    public function assign($key, $value, $overwrite = false) {
        if ($overwrite) {
            $this->vars[$key] = $value;
        } else if (isset($this->vars[$key])) {
            echo 'this var already exists!';
        } else {
            $this->vars[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function append($key, $value) {
        $this->vars[$key] .= $value;
    }

    public function setPage($page) {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

}
```

but I was wondering how I could add if & elses and foreach loops to the engine. I want it to look something like this in the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>        
    <body>
        [@if {bool} == true][ <!-- different expressions like {int} > 2 should work too -->
            <div>{text}</div>
        ]
        [@else][
            <div> error </div>
        ]

        [@foreach {jsLinks} as {jsLink}][
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{jsLink}"></script>
        ]
    </body>
</html>
```

the template files are saved as .php files, so I could do `<?php if($bool == true){?> some html <?php  }?>`,
but I don't want to use php code in the templating files.
Can anyone please help me with this?

**EDIT**

I added this code:

```
$content = preg_replace('~\{LOOP:(\w+)\}~', '<?php foreach ($this->vars[\'$1\'] as $ELEMENT): $this->wrap($ELEMENT); ?>', $content);
$content = preg_replace('~\{ENDLOOP:(\w+)\}~', '<?php $this->unwrap(); endforeach; ?>', $content);
```

and these two functions:

```
private function wrap($element){
    $this->stack[] = $this->vars;
    foreach ($element as $k => $v) {
        $this->vars[$k] = $v;
    }
}

private function unwrap() {
    $this->vars = array_pop($this->stack);
}
```

but this just echoes `<?php foreach ($this->vars[\'$1\'] as $ELEMENT): $this->wrap($ELEMENT); ?>` and `<?php $this->unwrap(); endforeach; ?>` literally in the browser. Any way to fix this?

**EDIT: I did it!**

I can now use foreach loops and ifs and elses in my templates. My template class:

```
<?php

class Template {

    private $vars = array();
    public $page;
    public $view;
    public $bDisplay = true;

    function __construct($view = false) {
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function render($render = false) {
        if ($this->bDisplay === true) {
            $page = PATH_VIEWS . $this->page . '.php';
            $page = (empty($this->page) ? ($this->view ? PATH_VIEWS . $this->view . DS . 'index.php' : PATH_VIEWS . 'index' . DS . 'index.php') : (file_exists($page) ? $page : PATH_VIEWS . 'index' . DS . 'index.php'));
            $content = file_get_contents($page);

            $content = $this->replace($content, $this->vars);

            $content = preg_replace('~\{LOOP:(\w+)\}~', '<?php foreach ($this->vars[\'$1\'] as $value){ echo  $this->replace(\'', $content);
            $content = preg_replace('~\{ENDLOOP:(\w+)\}~', '\', $value);} ?>', $content);

            $content = preg_replace('~\{IF:([^\r\n}]+)\}~', '<?php if ($1): echo \'', $content);
            $content = preg_replace('~\{ELSE\}~', '\'; else: echo \'', $content);
            $content = preg_replace('~\{ENDIF\}~', '\'; endif; ?>', $content);


            if ($render)
                eval('?>' . $content . '<?php');
            else
                return $content;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function replace($content, $vars) {
        foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($vars[$key])) {
                $tag = '{' . $key . '}';
                $content = str_replace($tag, $value, $content);
            }
        }

        return $content;
    }

    public function assign($key, $value, $overwrite = false) {
        if ($overwrite) {
            $this->vars[$key] = $value;
        } else if (isset($this->vars[$key])) {
            echo 'this var already exists!';
        } else {
            $this->vars[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function append($key, $value) {
        $this->vars[$key] .= $value;
    }

    public function addArray($array, $key, $value) {
        $this->vars[$array][][$key] = $value;
    }

    public function setPage($page) {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

}

?>
```

with as example template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!-- foreach loops -->
        {LOOP:js}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{link}"></script>
        {ENDLOOP}

        <!-- if statement -->        
        {IF: {bool} === true}
        display some text
        {ENDIF}

        <!-- if-else statement -->        
        {IF: {number} > 2}
        number is bigger than 2
        {ELSE}
        number is smaller than 2
        {ENDIF}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to implement a parser, or better a converter and register that as handler for those templates files. You might want to look at the "compiler compilers" typically found on unixoid systems: `bison` and `yacc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to write converter. For example, parse template and convert `[@if {bool} == true]` to `<?php if ($bool == true): ?>`.

Comment: And how do I do that? With regular expressions?

Comment: Also, look here https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php First comment says that parser uses "Precedence climbing" algorithm.

Comment: but then, what code could I use to do this? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Johan This is not a simple topic. You still need to parse the expression to know if a symbol is a variable or a literal etc. If you are stuck on the simplest of constructs ('if') it's probably better to sit back and rethink what you are doing. Looking into the source of Twig would be a good place to start. Also note that PHP itself is a templating engine (with to much power).